# Building VC++ 6 project from TeamCity. Can't find header files

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, teamcity, visual-c++-6

I have a VC++ project and I have got the .dsw file. I want to build the project through TeamCity and obtain the .dll file.

In the TeamCity, In Build Steps I have given the Runner type as Command Line and passing in the following parameters.

```
Myproject.dsw /MAKE "Myproject - Win32 Release MinSize"
```

It creates empty output directories and all but I get this error

```
fatal error RC1015:  cannot open include file 'afxres.h'
```

I have checked that the file is located at 'C:\ProgramFiles\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\MFC\Include'.
I don't understand why it is not picking up the file from this location. I tried adding this location to Environment Variable PATH, but it does not work.

The TeamCity picks up few files from 'C:\ProgramFiles\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\Include' though.

Please help.

Comment: A build system needs to be properly configured. The `%PATH%` environment variable is completely irrelevant.

Comment: I understand that %PATH% variable is not relevant here. But I just gave it a try with hope that it will work.

Comment: The error reported from resource compiler. It uses own include paths, most probably dsw uses default paths only

Comment: If I remember right "afxres.h" contains nothing of interest anyway for 99% of projects. I would just create an empty version of the file. At least try that and see where it gets you. Failing that google.

Comment: Use the Tools-Options command, go to the Directories tab and be sure that "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\MFC\INCLUDE" is part of the include files directories list.

Comment: John: Thanks for the comment but I would not go for that option. The project I am working for is huge and I don't know what this could lead to.
Michael: I checked the option suggested by you. The Directory for MFC is already added there. :( Any other option?

Comment: I found the solution to this. Please check my comments. Thanks for your help guys. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I some how figured out the solution for this.

The TeamCity Agent runs as a windows service. So, it can not access the User environment variable for e.g. %include% and %lib%.

What I did is, I passed these two variables as environment variables to TeamCity Build. And voila!!! It works. :)